# Safely Update Modify Active Directory Objects Using C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I've found many helpful answers regarding how to programmatically access and update Active Directory objects using C#, for example how to list group membership for a user account object or how to add a user account to a security group. I have also seen hints of warnings and suggestions to "Be careful", with no explanation of what to look out for.

What sort of damage can be caused by bad or in my case, novice coding practices? What steps should I take when modifying Active Directory objects via C# to ensure I am safely updating AD objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems too general...So only some general answers.

We can have a long list, but by the following points you will not be doing anything destructive I guess.

- Do all your coding practice in your test environment, not production.
  May be this is the only important point.
- Create new objects for your testing instead of using built-in ones.
- If you have >1 DC, don't power off for too long (e.g. 180 days, the tombstone period).
  If they have not replicated for too long, replication will always fail.
- You should seldom need to update schema and configuration naming context for normal code practice. If you do need to do so, make sure you know what you are doing.